# How to trim redirect url? from path to another path?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have an old site :

https://www.test.com/blogs/test/123-title

and wanted to redirect all dynamic url based on https://www.test.com/blogs/test/123-xxxxx -> 123-xxxx can be any dynamic title

into 
https://www.test.com/blog/xxxxx

so basicly I need to remove the "/blogs/test/123-xxxx" and change it into "/blog/xxxxx"

can we do that in htaccess?

as i am not familiar with this

thank you

attaching my htaccess code :

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on



############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>

        ############################################
        # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

        ############################################
        # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/blogs/test/[^-]+-(.+)$ /blog/$1 [END,R=301]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################


    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test/[^-]+-(.+)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# rest of rules go here
```

Comment: I updated my requirements can you please have a look :)

Comment: hmm its not working at all I put right below rewrite on

Comment: I have 2 site, one is website, one is blog, and the htaccess is shooting to the root website, where then I need to redirect to the blog website.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside the `/blog/` directory as well?

Comment: yes both have htaccess, but when I tried hitting the url, it loads the not found page of the root website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130839/discussion-between-boby-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

I have 2000+ old URLs like

```
website.com/hello/public/news
website.com/hello/public/notifications
website.com/hello/public/results
```

now I have trimmed 'hello/public' this part in the new version

so how do I write a generic redirect in .htaccess so if I get hit on these
it redirects to

```
website.com/news
website.com/notifications
website.com/results
```

and more ...